# Formula - Format Date?

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

I have a formula field whose return type is TEXT and below is the formula:

```
IF(Title_Release__c = TRUE, 'Released', TEXT(Expected_Titled_Date__c))
```

The result is as expected which is satisfactory but the date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD" but I would like to have it in this format "DD-MM-YYYY". Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the formula to this one it will give you the format

```
IF(Title_Release__c =TRUE,'Released',TEXT(DAY(Expected_Titled_Date__c))&'-'&TEXT(MONTH(Expected_Titled_Date__c))&'-'&TEXT(YEAR(Expected_Titled_Date__c))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want leading zeroes, you need to do a bit more work.

```
IF(DAY(Expected_Titled_Date__c) < 10, "0", "") & TEXT(DAY(Expected_Titled_Date__c)) & "-" &
IF(MONTH(Expected_Titled_Date__c) < 10, "0", "") & TEXT(MONTH(Expected_Titled_Date__c)) & "-" &
TEXT(YEAR(Expected_Titled_Date__c))
```